# Vector of structs with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, c++17, unique-ptr

I've already read many answers for the similar questions, but still cannot find a solution for my problem.

I have the struct:

```cpp
struct Param {
    std::string name;
    std::unique_ptr<Object> default_val;
};
```

I have the class `Function` that stores a vector of `Param`s.
Somewhere I create a vector of this params and need to pass it to `Function` constructor.

The problem is in the moment when I'm trying to pass vector to constructor.
I know that I need to move all `unique_ptr`s, and I do it.

Maybe I miss something pretty simple?

***`Code snippets`***

The `Function`:

```cpp
using Params = std::vector<Param>;

class Callable : public Object {
public:
    Callable(const Params & params) : params(params) {}
// ...
private:
    Params params;
}
```

The code where I create vector:

```cpp
Params params;
for(auto & p : func_decl->params){
    auto default_val = eval(p.default_val.get());
    Param p(p.id->get_name(), std::move(default_val));
    params.push_back(std::move(p));
}
```

Is it possible not to use here `shared_ptr`?

The output is:
`error: use of deleted function 'Param::Param(const Param&)'`

Comment: You haven't actually said what your problem is. What goes wrong? Please mark the exact line that gives the error as well.

Comment: @cigien, sorry, i edited

Comment: Try adding a move constructor `Callable(Params && params)` then I think they will be moved (it will quit using the `Param(const Param&)`

Comment: In which line do you get the error? What is the type of default_val? Can you please provide a [mcve]!?

Comment: Also, use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`

Comment: @wcochran `push_back` accepts rvalue references too: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Comment: @wcochran, since c++11, but before there was `emplace_back` instead. Anyway, I use c++17, so it doesn't matter

Comment: @hazer_hazer `push_back` will move, but I think its best to construct in place. Adding the move constructor to `Callable` will fix your problem. It is trying to copy and you can't copy unique_ptr's.

Comment: @wcochran, yes, thanks, i solved it, but cannot realise why cannot I call this constructor as `Callable(params)` where `params` is just a member of `this` `Callable`. (I wanna copy it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Param` is not copyable, because one of its member isn't. Since a vector is as copyable as its contents, then a vector of `Param` is not copyable.

When you do this:

```
Callable(const Params & params) : params(params) {}
```

You're trying to use vector's *copy constructor*. That won't compile.

You'll need to instead *move* the input vector, which will move its contents at the same time. That means changing the constructor so it takes an rvalue reference, and also use `std::move` to move the vector.

```
Callable(Params&& params) : params(std::move(params)) {}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've already tryied it, but I scared of another one thing. But it's the right solution.

Comment: @hazer_hazer If you tried the correct solution but didn't get it to work you should ask about that instead.

Comment: No, this worked, but I also had problem with `clone` method, that just create a copy of `Callable`, and it receive `params` that is lvalue, but `std::move` didn't work, so i was scared and moved back to previous version:) Sorry, if it sound unprofessional, i'm not pretty good at c++

Comment: The `clone` method is `virtual` in `Object` and implemented in the decendants, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, it return `unique_ptr<Object>`. But I cannot pass my `Callable` `params` to `Callable` constructor as `params` inside `Callable` is just a value, but constructor needs `Params && params`. And `std::move` does not work

Comment: @hazer_hazer It sounds like you should make a [mcve] and ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, don't mind it, I've solved everything. Thanks, everyone